# Apache virtual host with two document root directories

Tags: apache, config

I have two directories `/foo` and `/bar`. The content of both directories should be used as my DocumentRoot.

I tried this by adding `DocumentRoot` and `Alias/Directory`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/foo"
    ServerName local.php
    Alias / /bar/
    <Directory "/bar">
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I delete `Alias/Directory` only the files from `/foo` are served. If it's there only files from `/bar` are served.

How can I make apache use both directories?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. For instance if you have two files or directories with the same name under `/foo` and `/bar` what will be displayed to the client?

Comment: May be on takes precedence over the other?

Comment: This link might be of some use: http://madbean.com/2007/two-docroots/

Comment: @Krister Andersson: This works great. Feal free to add your comment as an answer to get the credits.